# C++ Even Numbers Lab submission Query

Tags: c++

Hi there? Here is my code, what could be the errors because it is correct when I run it?Write a program that reads a positive integer n, and prints the first
n even numbers.

For example, one execution would look like this:
Please enter a positive integer: 3
2
4
6

File Name

evennumbers.cpp

Score

There are three tests each worth 2 points

Autograder Results

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int n;
   cout<<"Please enter a positive integer:";
   cin>>n;
   cout<<"These are all positive integers in between 1 to "<<n<<"  "<<endl;
   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
       if(i%2==0)
           cout<<i<<"   "<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Evaluating Test 1 Output (0.0/2.0)
Test Failed: 'these are all positive integers in between 1 to 3  2' != '246'

- these are all positive integers in between 1 to 3  2

- 246
  Evaluating Test 2 Output (0.0/2.0)
  Test Failed: 'these are all positive integers in between 1 to 2  2' != '24'

- these are all positive integers in between 1 to 2  2

- 24
  Evaluating Test 3 Output (0.0/2.0)
  Test Failed: 'these are all positive integers in between 1 to 4  2   4' != '2468'

- these are all positive integers in between 1 to 4  2   4

- 2468

Comment: Replace`   cout<<"These are all positive integers in between 1 to "<<n<<"  "<<endl;
   for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
       if(i%2==0)
           cout<<i<<"   "<<endl;` with ` 
           cout<<2*i;`

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

1. Your program is not doing what was asked. It is currently printing every even number between `1` and `n`; when the problem asks you to print all the first `n` even numbers. So if `n` is `3`, you should print all the first three even numbers, that is, `2 4 6`.
2. Considering your program is being run through an automatic checker, you should print only what is asked. So don't print `these are all positives (...)`. Print only the even numbers you should print, given the input number. For instance, if the input is `3`, print only `2 4 6`. Don't print `these are all positive integers between 1 to 3 2 4 6`.